# What tensorflow.exp(...) does in code sample from edward tutorial

Tags: python, tensorflow, exp, edward

I am new to edward and checking the [tutorial about linear mixed effects](http://edwardlib.org/tutorials/linear-mixed-effects-models) (jupyter notebook can be found [here](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/blei-lab/edward/blob/master/notebooks/linear_mixed_effects_models.ipynb)) trying to understand the code. This question might be more related to me not understanding something ternsorflow though.

the code in the link  does:

```
sigma_s = tf.sqrt(tf.exp(tf.get_variable("sigma_s", [])))
sigma_d = tf.sqrt(tf.exp(tf.get_variable("sigma_d", [])))
sigma_dept = tf.sqrt(tf.exp(tf.get_variable("sigma_dept", [])))
```

I would guess what happens here is we define sigma_xxx to be the sigma square,a and then needs to do `tf.sqrt` to get the sigma. However, I really do not understand this `tf.exp`... What is it doing here and what is raised to which exponent???

Comment: [`tf.exp`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/exp) is the exponential function, it computes eˣ. Here the variables appear to be logarithms of the quantities you mention, which makes it easier to model because they can take any real value instead of just positive ones.